# Xamarin.Forms: ListView not Displaying in Android

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml

Good Day. I'm creating a simple Xamarin.Forms (Portable) application that allows me to create record of an Employee and saved it on a Database in Visual Studio. All records are being displayed to a ListView.

My application is doing fine when I run it on UWP. It displays the all the created records on a ListView properly.

But when I run it on Android Platform, it does not display any record in the ListView. I even tried to check on the Web API whether it returns a value or not. And I did get a value. Meaning, the problem is on Android Platform why it isn't displaying any record.

Have you encountered this problem? What do you think is the reason behind this? What can I do now? Sorry I'm just a newbie here in Xamarin. Hope you can help me. Thanks a lot.

These are some codes I have:

**EmployeeRecordsPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.EmployeeRecordsPage"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinFormsDemo"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
         BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
         Title="List of Employees">


  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">


    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesList}"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
        >
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <controls:CircleImage Source="icon.png"
               HeightRequest="66"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               Aspect="AspectFill"
               WidthRequest="66"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               />


        <Label Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding EMPLOYEE_NAME}"
               TextColor="#24e97d"
               FontSize="24"/>



      <Label Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="1"
               Text="{Binding EMP_NUMBER}"
               TextColor="White"
               FontSize="18"
               Opacity="0.6"/>


        <Label Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Text="{Binding DEPT_COMP}"
             TextColor="White"
             FontSize="18"
             Opacity="0.6"/>



          </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

  </ListView>


<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
         Padding="30,10,30,10"
         HeightRequest="20"
         BackgroundColor="#24e97d"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         Opacity="0.5">
  <Label Text="© Copyright 2016   SMESOFT.COM.PH   All Rights Reserved "
         HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>



</ContentPage>
```

..

**EmployeeViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Services;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private List<Employee> _employeesList;
        private Employee _selectedEmployee = new Employee();




    public List<Employee> EmployeesList
    {
        get { return _employeesList; }
        set
        {
            _employeesList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }



    public MainViewModel()
    {
        InitializeDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
    {
        var employeesServices = new EmployeesServices();

        EmployeesList = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    }
}
```

..

**EmployeesServices.cs**

```
using Plugin.RestClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Services
{
   public class EmployeesServices
    {

    public async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsync()
    {
        RestClient<Employee> restClient = new RestClient<Employee>();

        var employeesList = await restClient.GetAsync();

        return employeesList;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show you MainActivity for android ? Did you try to put a break-point in the Xamarin Forms Page and check if it is getting hit ?

Comment: @user3185569 I haven't tried putting a breakpoint Sir. I don't know yet how to. Here's my code for MainActivity. http://pastie.org/10906729

Comment: The issue is not jumping out at me with the code shown. Can you provide a sample project to run?

Comment: @therealjohn Alright Sir. Can I get you email and I'll just send it to you if it's okay?

Comment: @user3185569 Have you checked my codes Sir?

Comment: File an issue here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ and you can attach a project privately. Then, send me a link to the bug and I will check it out.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is that you are not updating the ListView after you get your items with:

```
EmployeesList = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();
```

I would suggest using an ObservableCollection instead of a List. With an observable collection the ListView should get updated automatically when items in the ObservableCollection are added or deleted. So instead of:

```
private List<Employee> _employeesList;
```

try:

```
private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employeesList;
```

or you can just assign the `ListView.ItemsSource` to `null` and then back to the `List<Employee>` after you get your data:

EDIT: As noted by Jaycee, the following code to reset the ItemsSource should not be in the view model as the view model won't have access to `listView`. However the way to refresh the `listView.ItemsSource` is correct. The view model just needs to let the view know that the `EmployeesList` was updated and then you can reset the `listView.ItemsSource` in the code behind for the view. This could be done in a couple of ways I can think of. For instance you could have a delegate in the ViewModel that the view can provide the code implementation for or the view model could raise an event that the view can subscribe to. Basically you just have to let the view know that it needs to refresh its `ListView`'s `ItemsSource`. But all of this could be avoided by using an `ObservableCollection` instead of a list as I noted previously.

```
EmployeesList = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();
listView.ItemsSource = null;
listView.ItemsSource = EmployeesList;
```

And to do the above you would have to give your ListView a name that you can use to reference it in code. YOu can set this name in the XAML for the ListView:

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesList}"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
    x:Name="listView"
>
```

But the ObservableCollection would be the preferable option.

Comment: Sir Why can't I access the listView in my ViewModel even if I declared it in here : x:Name="listView"

Comment: It will be available in your code behind file for the Xaml page, not the view model. I am not an MVVM expert but as far as I understand it, ideally the ViewModel should not need to know anything about the view, since a view ViewModel could potentially be used for more than one view. So you might want to have your ViewModel raise an event when EmployeesList is loaded and your view code behind can subscribe to that event so it can reload the ItemsSource for the listView.

Comment: Yes Sir it is available in my code behind. So therefore what you did here is not correct: EmployeesList = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();
listView.ItemsSource = null;
listView.ItemsSource = EmployeesList;

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that that code was in your view model. However my answer was essentially correct with the exception of where to put the code to refresh the listView, so please accept it.

Comment: Alright Sir I'll accept your answer, no problem with that. I just want to know how am I going to access the EmployeesList in my code behind?

Comment: If `EmployeesList` is a public property, and you have a reference to your View Model in the code behind, then you should be able to access `EmployeesList` in your code behind.